# Regla Rewrite para urls amigables con un parámetro adicional

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

Tengo a mi script está en:

```
www.miproyecto.com/main/admin/organization/script.php
```

Este script contiene un parámetro que es opcional. En mi `.htaccess` tengo lo siguiente:

```
RewriteRule ^my-script/(/.*)?$ main/admin/organization/script.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Me funciona perfecto si paso el parámetro, pero sin el parámetro no funciona.

¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Si bien tiene respuesta la pregunta, creo que deberías especificar qué se haría en cada caso, mostrando ejemplos de cómo se haría la redirección (desde-hasta) para cada uno.

Answer (score 0):

Se pueden generar diferentes reglas dentro del mismo `.htaccess`, la primera para redirigir cuando no lleva parámetros, y la segunda cuando tiene parámetros:

```python
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^my-script/?$          main/admin/organization/script.php       [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^my-script/(.*[^/])/?$ main/admin/organization/script.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Aquí hay dos formas de resolver el problema, pero depende que cómo quieres que funcione. La primera sería indicarle al motor de reescritura que el parámetro no es opcional simplemente cambiando `*` por `+` y quitando `?` así:

```
RewriteRule ^my-script/(/.+)$ main/admin/organization/script.php?id=$1 [L]
```

En caso que no haya ningún parámetro, la regla no coincidirá y contestará normalmente `my-script/index.(php|html)`. La segunda opción es manejar el valor vacío `''` para `$_GET['id']` en `script.php`.